# How to make multiple \footnotemark and \footnotetext match?

Tags: beamer, footnotes, block

As the title, I want to insert two pairs of `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` in the `block` environment, but the superscript number of the `mark` is different (e.g. 3 and 4), but the superscript number for the `text` is the same (e.g. 4).

```
\begin{filecontents}{citation.bib}
@Article{Yazdanpanah2014,
  author   = {F. Yazdanpanah and C. Alvarez-Martinez and D. Jimenez-Gonzalez and Y. Etsion},
  title    = {Hybrid Dataflow/von-Neumann Architectures},
  journal  = {IEEE Transactions on Parallel and Distributed Systems},
  year     = {2014},
  volume   = {25},
  number   = {6},
  pages    = {1489--1509},
  month    = jun,
  issn     = {1045-9219},
  doi      = {10.1109/TPDS.2013.125},
}
@InProceedings{Amdahl1967,
author        = {Amdahl, Gene M.},
title         = {Validity of the Single Processor Approach to Achieving Large Scale Computing Capabilities},
booktitle     = {Proceedings of the April 18-20, 1967, Spring Joint Computer Conference},
year          = {1967},
series        = {AFIPS '67 (Spring)},
pages         = {483--485},
address       = {New York, NY, USA},
publisher     = {ACM},
__markedentry = {[Administrator:6]},
acmid         = {1465560},
doi           = {10.1145/1465482.1465560},
location      = {Atlantic City, New Jersey},
numpages      = {3},
url           = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/1465482.1465560},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[utf8, xcolor=table]{beamer}  
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,isbn=false,doi=false,sorting=none,url=false,style=ieee]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{citation.bib}    
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{this is a block\footnotemark}
    this is the context\footnotemark.
\end{block}
\footnotetext{\fullcite{Amdahl1967}}
\footnotetext{\fullcite{Yazdanpanah2014}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\footnotetext[1]{\fullcite{Amdahl1967}}` can be used to set the number to, in this case, `1`.  If you are worried about problems during renumeration, then `\footnotetext[\numexpr\thefootnote-1]{\fullcite{Amdahl1967}}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, it works, but if there is a new citation inserted between them, the constant `1` in the expression is required to be modified, is there an other way the keep it automatically renumbering?

Comment: You could do something like `\addtocounter{footnote}{-2}
\footnotetext{\fullcite{Amdahl1967}}\stepcounter{footnote}
\footnotetext{\fullcite{Yazdanpanah2016}}\stepcounter{footnote}
\footnotetext{\fullcite{Yazdanpanah2014}}`.  The initial number to subtract will be 1 less than the number of `\footnotemark`s on the slide.

Answer (score 6):

In my comments, I showed ways to play with optional arguments to `\footnotetext` to fix the problem.  I also showed ways to play with the `footnote` counter.

However, the *real* way to fix this is to issue the `\footnotetext` macros immediately after the corresponding `\footnotemark`s.  This is because the invocation of `\footnotemark` steps the `footnote` counter.  And that is the proper time to issue the `\footnotetext` invocation unless your environment precludes it.

```
\begin{filecontents}{citation.bib}
@Article{Yazdanpanah2014,
  author   = {F. Yazdanpanah and C. Alvarez-Martinez and D. Jimenez-Gonzalez and Y. Etsion},
  title    = {Hybrid Dataflow/von-Neumann Architectures},
  journal  = {IEEE Transactions on Parallel and Distributed Systems},
  year     = {2014},
  volume   = {25},
  number   = {6},
  pages    = {1489--1509},
  month    = jun,
  issn     = {1045-9219},
  doi      = {10.1109/TPDS.2013.125},
}
@InProceedings{Amdahl1967,
author        = {Amdahl, Gene M.},
title         = {Validity of the Single Processor Approach to Achieving Large Scale Computing Capabilities},
booktitle     = {Proceedings of the April 18-20, 1967, Spring Joint Computer Conference},
year          = {1967},
series        = {AFIPS '67 (Spring)},
pages         = {483--485},
address       = {New York, NY, USA},
publisher     = {ACM},
__markedentry = {[Administrator:6]},
acmid         = {1465560},
doi           = {10.1145/1465482.1465560},
location      = {Atlantic City, New Jersey},
numpages      = {3},
url           = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/1465482.1465560},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[utf8, xcolor=table]{beamer}  
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,isbn=false,doi=false,sorting=none,url=false,style=ieee]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{citation.bib}    
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    this is the extraneous footmark\footnotemark.
\footnotetext{Just some text}
\begin{block}{this is a block\footnotemark}
\footnotetext{\fullcite{Amdahl1967}}
    this is the context\footnotemark.
\footnotetext{\fullcite{Yazdanpanah2014}}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this way, but the `footnotetext` was still inside the `block`.

Comment: If you call `\footnotetext` inside a minipage, it can break the formatting of your slide by trying to put the footnote under that minipage (column) instead at the end of the frame. So you must wait to call it after the minipage, and if you have two citations in one minipage, you can't have it count properly with this method.

Comment: @T.ZackCrawford Thanks for the warning. As I said at the end of my answer, "unless your environment precludes it".  And, for the reasons you cite, it would seem that inside a `minipage` is not a good place to use this technique.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Nevermind, I managed to get it to work by adjusting the counter like you mention in the second comment to the OP. Just blindly use `\footnotemark{}` in the minipage when expected. Then **OUTSIDE** the minipage, set back the counter `\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}\footnotetext{\fullcite{foo}}` and manually step for the rest of the slide `\addtocounter{footnote}{1}\footnotetext{\fullcite{bar}}`

Answer (score 2):

The matter is that `\footnotemark` also increases its counter, so maintaining a private counter solves the problem:

```latex
% replace existing \footnotetext with \note
\newcounter{note}
\newcommand{\note}[1] {
    \stepcounter{note}
    \footnotetext[\arabic{note}]{#1}
}
```