# Using multiple footnote-citations per page in a column environment

Tags: beamer, biblatex, footnotes

So, I want to use multiple citations on one page in a `beamer` presentation slide. On this page I have a `column` environment and thus have to use `footnotemark` and `footcitetext`, at least I thought so. This is my approach:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\begin{filecontents*}{test_bib.bib} 
    @book{Peter1, 
        author={Peter Muller}, 
        title={My life as Peter Mueller}, 
        address={Peterstown}, 
        publisher={Petersen family},
        year={2017}
    } 
    @book{Uwe1, 
        author={Uwe Ha}, 
        title={Notes about Peter Mueller}, 
        address={Chicago}, 
        publisher={Worldclass Publisher},
        year={2008}
}
    @book{Klaus1,
        author={Klaus Pe}, 
        title={On the relation between Uwe Ha and Peter Muller}, 
        address={New York}, 
        publisher={Second Worldclass Publisher},
        year={2018}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[
    style=verbose,
    autocite=footnote,
    backend=biber,
    ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test_bib.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Two columns on this page}
    \begin{columns}[T]
        \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
          \begin{itemize}
              \item Some text in the first column
              \item More text\footnotemark
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Guess what: more text\footnotemark
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \footcitetext{Peter1}
    \footcitetext{Uwe1}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{One column on this page}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Even more text\footnotemark
    \end{itemize}
    \footcitetext{Klaus1}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Bibliography}
    \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The numbers in the footnotes on the first page with the two column are not correct as can be seen from the following screenshot: [image: Footnote numbering incorrect]

Any advice on what I am doing wrong is greatly appreciated!

Edit: I am compiling with `xelatex biber xelatex xelatex`

Comment: Maybe this can help you: [How to make multiple \footnotemark and \footnotetext match?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/370600/134144)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the place you are calling the \footcitetext command to give clearly to LaTeX understand where it supposed to be:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\begin{filecontents*}{test_bib.bib} 
    @book{Peter1, 
        author={Peter Muller}, 
        title={My life as Peter Mueller}, 
        address={Peterstown}, 
        publisher={Petersen family},
        year={2017}
    } 
    @book{Uwe1, 
        author={Uwe Ha}, 
        title={Notes about Peter Mueller}, 
        address={Chicago}, 
        publisher={Worldclass Publisher},
        year={2008}
}
    @book{Klaus1,
        author={Klaus Pe}, 
        title={On the relation between Uwe Ha and Peter Muller}, 
        address={New York}, 
        publisher={Second Worldclass Publisher},
        year={2018}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[
    style=verbose,
    autocite=footnote,
    backend=biber,
    ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test_bib.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Two columns on this page}
    \begin{columns}[T]
        \begin{column}{0.4\textwidth}
          \begin{itemize}
              \item Some text in the first column
              \item More text\footnotemark
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \footcitetext{Peter1}
        \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Guess what: more text\footnotemark
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \footcitetext{Uwe1}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{One column on this page}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Even more text\footnotemark
    \end{itemize}
    \footcitetext{Klaus1}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Bibliography}
    \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: ohh, I thought `footnotecite` had to be outside of the `columns` environment, thanks!

Comment: Welcome and happy TeXing!